# How to apply a function on specific columns of a dataframe using `select`?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Say I have the following `df`:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(categ = ["a", "a", "a", "b"], numer = [1, 2, 3, 4])

#4×2 DataFrame
# Row │ categ   numer
#     │ String  Int64
#─────┼───────────────
#   1 │ a           1
#   2 │ a           2
#   3 │ a           3
#   4 │ b           4
```

Now I want to perform a frequency encoding **on the categorical variables (note that I just provided a minimal example and the number of categorical vars may reach hundreds)** and the expected result is:

```
 4×2 DataFrame
  Row │ categ    numer
      │ Float64  Int64
 ─────┼────────────────
    1 │    0.75      1
    2 │    0.75      2
    3 │    0.75      3
    4 │    0.25      4
```

I achieved it using:

```
select(
  df,
  :categ => ByRow(x->count(==(x), df.categ)/size(df, 1))=>:categ,
  :numer)
```

It works, But it's not generic:

1. I performed the operation just on the `:categ` var. A workaround can be passing `names(df, String)`.
2. I used `df.categ` in the `count` function and it's not generic. What if I had 100 categorical vars?
3. I manually kept `:numer` intact, and it's not generic. What if I had 100 numerical vars?

Update:
I tried using `names(df, Not(String))` for the third problem. But it doesn't work. I know that I can say `names(df, Int64)`, but I don't want to limit it to `Int64` only. I might had `Complex` vars as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be efficient and generic:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(categ = ["a", "a", "a", "b"], categ2 = ["a", "b", "b", "b"], numer = [1, 2, 3, 4])
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ categ   categ2  numer
     │ String  String  Int64
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │ a       a           1
   2 │ a       b           2
   3 │ a       b           3
   4 │ b       b           4

julia> transform(df, names(df, String) .=> (x -> select(groupby(DataFrame(x=x), :x), proprow, keepkeys=false).proprow), renamecols=false)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ categ    categ2   numer
     │ Float64  Float64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │    0.75     0.25      1
   2 │    0.75     0.75      2
   3 │    0.75     0.75      3
   4 │    0.25     0.75      4
```

If the function looks too long for you then do:

```
julia> freqrow(x) = select(groupby(DataFrame(x=x), :x), proprow, keepkeys=false).proprow
freqrow (generic function with 1 method)

julia> transform(df, names(df, String) .=> freqrow, renamecols=false)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ categ    categ2   numer
     │ Float64  Float64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │    0.75     0.25      1
   2 │    0.75     0.75      2
   3 │    0.75     0.75      3
   4 │    0.25     0.75      4
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
julia> df2 = copy(df);

julia> for col in names(df2, String)
           df2 = transform(groupby(df2, col), proprow => col, copycols=false, keepkeys=false)
       end

julia> df2
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ categ    categ2   numer
     │ Float64  Float64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │    0.75     0.25      1
   2 │    0.75     0.75      2
   3 │    0.75     0.75      3
   4 │    0.25     0.75      4
```

which maybe is easier to digest.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what is going on in the `select`? (in the first solution I mean). Thank you so much. I think you're creating a DataFrame from each given column, and performed grouping on the column, and applying the `proprow` on all columns of the temporary DataFrame (which only has a column `x`). Am I right? But I didn't get the last piece: `.proprow` (and `keepkeys=false`).

Comment: This is exactly what I do and that is why it is efficient (as `groupby` is fast and in one pass it gets counts of all groups). The last `.proprow` just extracts column with `:proprow` name from the result (by default this is is the name of the column with proportions if you do not specify one).